# How to delete columns of a table in mysql where all values are null for that column. I have 38GB table so performance is required.

Tags: mysql

I have a huge DB table(38 GB) in which there are many columns which are having all its value as null. Problem is that before creating table you are not aware which columns will have data and due to that we have to keep all columns while creating table. But due to this performance of queries are very bad.

So need to find all columns which have all its value null reduce size of table. Also when inner joins are done it takes too much of time. So is it the case that inner join on large tables takes more time.

Comment: "before creating table you are not aware which columns will have data" <facepalm/> Try dba.stackexchange.com and you may get a better answer.

Comment: null columns are probably not the cause of the poor performance; what real evidence do you have that says it is?

Comment: May be not, but I suspect they add to size
and hence performance. I am not good in DB , so need advice.

Comment: "*But due to this performance of queries are very bad*" - how do you know? Did you test it? Or is this just a guess because you heard a myth that claims that null values slow down retrieval.

Comment: This is just a guess because in 300 columns almost more than 100 columns don't have any value, so is it possible that null values are adding to the size of db table and slowing up things for self join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a

```
SELECT Count(distinct colName) FROM myTable
```

For eacht column. This way you will get  als only result if there is no other value. You can then

```
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP COLUMN colName
```

to drop the col.

An **alternative** might be that you do a

```
SELECT * FROM myTable procedure Analyse()
```

This way you will get an overview on your table with all columns containing two interesting columns: `Empties_or_zeros` and `Nulls`. Both contain the Count of empty rows.